# Moving frameless window by dragging it from a portion of client area

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi, custom-controls

As the title says, I would like to move the window only when the user will drag it from a portion of the client area. This will be an imitation of the normal caption bar movement and it's because my form is custom and it doesn't have any title or caption bars. At the moment, I use the code as follows:

```
...
case WM_NCHITTEST:
        return HTCAPTION;
```

and that works fine for making the user able to move the window no matter where he drags from. I would like to limit this possibility (only the top of the window will allow movement). I haven't tried checking the position of the mouse pressed because I don't know how to do it in the `WM_NCHITTEST` message.
I use plain Win32 (winapi) C code (no MFC or anything else at the moment) in Visual Studio 2015.

[image: My custom window]

Comment: There is no language called C/C++. Please tell us which of the two you are programming in and remove the other tag.

Comment: Use GetMessagePos() to get the cursor position if a message doesn't provide it.

Comment: @FUZxxl It means C or C++. OP is looking for an answer in either, because WinAPI and VS2015 support both. Both tags are appropriate.

Comment: @2501 As discussed elsewhere, this kind of question is discouraged because “C/C++” often actually means “Actually I need C++ but if there is a C answer I can probably twist it into something useful anyway.” Ask for what you need, not for what yields the broadest possible audience.

Comment: Specifying the correct language is important. I looked at the tags to see what type of casts to use, for example. No idea. I rolled the dice and picked C++. It is only this easy because the question is entirely about Win32, which is a C API and therefore the code looks very similar in both languages. In the future, please do pick a language and stick with it. Having to repeat this comment discussion *ad nauseum* gets old.

Comment: I'm sorry about the discussion. I meant C and I didn't want to reach the broadest possible audience, it's just I'm not an expert and I'm sorry again for that :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will run into trouble if you just return `HTCAPTION` in response to *all* `WM_NCHITTEST` messages. You will break things like scrollbars, close buttons, resizing borders, etc. that are all implemented via different `HT*` values.

You have the right idea, though. You want to make the client area of your window draggable, so you need to trick Windows into thinking that your client area is actually the caption area (which, as you know, is draggable). That code looks like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // ...
    case WM_NCHITTEST:
    {
        // Call the default window procedure for default handling.
        const LRESULT result = ::DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

        // You want to change HTCLIENT into HTCAPTION.
        // Everything else should be left alone.
        return (result == HTCLIENT) ? HTCAPTION : result;
    }
    // ...
}
```

However, based on the image in your question, you appear to want to restrict this to only a certain region of your window. You will need to define exactly what that area is, and then hit-test to see if the user has clicked in that area. Assuming that `rcDraggable` is a `RECT` structure that contains the bounds of [the red box shown in your image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylh0R.png) (in screen coordinates), you can use the following code:

```
static RECT rcDraggable = ...

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // ...
    case WM_NCHITTEST:
    {
        // Call the default window procedure for default handling.
        const LRESULT result = ::DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

        // Get the location of the mouse click, which is packed into lParam.
        POINT pt;
        pt.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
        pt.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

        // You want to change HTCLIENT into HTCAPTION for a certain rectangle, rcDraggable.
        // Everything else should be left alone.
        if ((result == HTCLIENT) && (PtInRect(&rcDraggable, pt))
        {
            return HTCAPTION;
        }
        return result;
    }
    // ...
}
```

If you define `rcDraggable` in terms of client coordinates, you will need to convert it to screen coordinates before doing the hit-testing in response to `WM_NCHITTEST`. To do that, call the [`MapWindowPoints` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145046.aspx), like so:

```
RECT rc = rcDraggable;
MapWindowPoints(hWnd,   /* a handle to your window       */
                NULL,   /* convert to screen coordinates */
                reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&rc),
                (sizeof(RECT) / sizeof(POINT)));
```

Comment: I implemented this code but it doesn't work even if I think it is correct.
`static RECT rcDraggable = {1, 1, 949, 80}; // left, top, right, bottom` as global variable, then
    `case WM_NCHITTEST:
  {
   const LRESULT result = ::DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
   
   POINT pt;
   pt.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
   pt.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

   RECT rc = rcDraggable;
   MapWindowPoints(hwnd, NULL, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&rc), (sizeof(RECT) / sizeof(POINT)));

   if ((result == HTCLIENT) && (PtInRect(&rcDraggable, pt)))
    return HTCAPTION;
   return result;
  }`

Comment: Don't copy/paste the answer in that way. You have `rc` in correct screen coordinates for use in `WM_NCHITTEST`, but then you ignore `rc` and you look at `rcDraggable` which is still in client coordinates. Use `PtInRect(&rc, pt)` instead

Comment: Yeah, you have to use the right rectangles, otherwise you'll get the wrong results. `MapWindowPoints` modifies the rectangle in-place.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem. I apologize, it was so easy to find out my error but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can call some magic code in WM_LBUTTONDOWN handler, AFAIR this:

```
 ReleaseCapture();
 SendMessage(yourWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xf012, 0) ;
```

I used this method a few years ago in Delphi and Windows XP. I think it must be similar for c++. Of course, you can check x and y before doing this.

Comment: FYI, `0xF012` is `SC_DRAGMOVE`, which is `SC_MOVE` and `HTCAPTION` OR'ed together.

Comment: ...which is an undocumented value, so using it like this gives the backwards-compatibility team headaches. Oh well, I guess it is too late now to ever change it.